# How to add data row into GridView Database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I've been searching around on internet i'm new to this C# & asp.net how to add new row and insert data at Gridview?? I've success attach it with my database. When i try with ListView i can make it with Insert data function but the display is insufficient to show all my data table.
I've search around and have no idea how to deal with the code behind stuff. i'm a total fresh to these, i need to do it for submit my assignment. kindly help me please.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ResinPrice.aspx.cs" Inherits="MQM_System.ResinPrice" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowSorting="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="SN">
        <Columns>

            <asp:BoundField DataField="SN" HeaderText="SN" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="SN" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="MaterialDescription" 
                HeaderText="MaterialDescription" SortExpression="MaterialDescription" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" 
                SortExpression="Location" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PreviousUpdate" HeaderText="PreviousUpdate" 
                SortExpression="PreviousUpdate" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateUpdate" HeaderText="DateUpdate" 
                SortExpression="DateUpdate" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="25kg" HeaderText="25kg" SortExpression="25kg" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="100kg" HeaderText="100kg" SortExpression="100kg" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="250kg" HeaderText="250kg" SortExpression="250kg" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="500kg" HeaderText="500kg" SortExpression="500kg" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="1ton" HeaderText="1ton" SortExpression="1ton" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="2ton" HeaderText="2ton" SortExpression="2ton" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="5ton" HeaderText="5ton" SortExpression="5ton" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="10ton" HeaderText="10ton" SortExpression="10ton" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="25ton" HeaderText="25ton" SortExpression="25ton" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Mfr" HeaderText="Mfr" SortExpression="Mfr" />

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>


    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:flextronic singaporeConnectionString %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:flextronic singaporeConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM resin_price" 
        DeleteCommand="DeleteCommand=&quot;DELETE FROM resin_price WHERE S/N = ?&quot; " 
        InsertCommand="InsertCommand=&quot;INSERT INTO resin_price (SN, Material_Description, Location, Previous_Update, Date_Update, 25kg, 100kg, 250kg, 500kg, 1ton, 2ton, 5ton, 10ton, 25ton, Mfr) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)&quot; " 
        UpdateCommand="UpdateCommand=&quot;UPDATE resin_price SET Material_Description = ?, Location = ?, Previous_Update = ?, Date_Update = ?, 25kg = ?, 100kg = ?, 250kg = ?, 500kg = ?, 1ton = ?, 2ton = ?, 5ton = ?, 10ton = ?, 25ton = ?, Mfr = ? WHERE SN = ?&quot;&gt;"></asp:SqlDataSource>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: This is way too broad question to answer here. There are multiple things you need to consider, multiple paths to take.. You need to learn to separate UI from logic etc etc. It isn't a thing you learn over night. We're not here to teach you things you didn't understand at school...

Comment: I just need to know how to add Empty text box with attach with my database into this GridView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find a clue to do that:

[How to easily insert row in GridView with SqlDataSource?](http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/How-to-insert-row-in-GridView-with-SqlDataSource.aspx)